# Selecting two other datagridview rows after selecting first, related on 'rptId' field

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have three datagridviews in a windows form, and want to be able to automatically have the two other datagridviews to select their respective rows, based on a rptID column value.
All three datagridviews are different sql tables, related by the rptID.

I have been able to pull the rptID from all three dgv's within a click event with this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int rptIdValue1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString());   
        }
```

My problem is figuring out how, with this rptID value, to compare it to the two other dgv's, and select the corresponding dgv row (i.e. Click rptId 51 and then auto-select the corresponding rptID rows in the two other dgv's).

I appreciate any help that is given. I tried to post a pic of my form, but don't have enough rep point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at this example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var rptIdValue1 = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)r.Cells[0].Value != rptIdValue1) continue;

            dataGridView2.Rows[r.Index].Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

You have to check for null and try/catch ...

Cheers,
Martin

Comment: Martin, I have text boxes next to the datagridviews that are populated with the values from each row's field.  When the the .selected event happens, the selected row changes in the other dgv's, but the data doesn't populate in the text boxes.  Do you know off the top of your head why that is?  Would I have to set the newly selected row as the "currentrow"?  Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Martin, I was able to figure it out.  It works how I want it to now.  Thanks for the reply.   Here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var rptIdValue1 = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r2 in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if ((int)r2.Cells[0].Value != rptIdValue1)
                    continue;

                dataGridView2.Rows[r2.Index].Selected = true;
                dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[r2.Index].Cells[0];
                break;                           
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r3 in dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                int dgv3Index = (int)dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].RowIndex;

                if ((int)r3.Cells[0].Value != rptIdValue1) 
                    continue;

                dataGridView3.Rows[r3.Index].Selected = true;
                dataGridView3.CurrentCell = dataGridView3.Rows[r3.Index].Cells[0];
                break;                            
            }

    }
```